# What is max concurrent connections on MySql Database and it is low on my database

Tags: android, mysql

I am using MySql Database to connect my website to my android app. My android app is for Live TV. Now the problem is that since two days everytime there are more than 250 users that i have seen the app cant be oppened. While searching i found out that a part on my database says this

```
Connections                  #  ø per hour  %
Max. concurrent connections 215   ---       ---
```

Can someone please help me what might be the problem that my app does this? I also upgraded to cloud hosting to see any difference

Comment: Connections to the database are normally transient i.e. open, quick poke about, get out. So 1000 of users can actually work within a 250 connection limit. What is your app doing that is keeping a connection from being reused?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would lie if i said i know anything about MySQL . If i go to the database stats i can see that:Aborted clients 39.9 k -The number of connections that were aborted because the client died without closing the connection properly.
Aborted 2.6 M -The number of failed attempts to connect to the MySQL server.

Comment: So what language do you use on the server to access the database? Can you show us that code

Comment: @RiggsFolly The website is Php and it connects with an Api Key to the App.What code do you need from me? Thanks For The Help

Comment: Have you configured the max_connections for the mysql server? What you get if you run: show global variables LIKE 'max_connections'